# Sending Mail From Laravel

Tags: email, laravel-4, config

I am attempting to send mail from a Laravel app but can't quite get it to work. I have an email address set up on the server through cPanel and would like to be able to send from that email in Laravel.

In Codeigniter I could simply leave the config file empty like this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => '',
        'smtp_host' => '',
        'smtp_port' => '',
        'smtp_user' => '',
        'smtp_pass' => '',
        'mailtype'  => '',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );
```

And send using a script like this:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'Test Person');
        $this->email->to('test@hotmail.com');            

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

        $this->email->send();
```

What is the equivalent set up in Laravel? I can't leave the SMPT host blank or it throws an error. If I change the driver to 'mail', and leave everything else blank, it will not throw an error but I will not receive an email.

Here is the Laravel mail config for good measure:

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'mail',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

//'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    'host' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

//'port' => 587,
'port' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

//'username' => null,
    'username' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

//'password' => null,
    'password' => '',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

);
```

Comment: Add your email address in the 'address' key value and your name in the 'name' key value in your 'from' array.  Not having a 'from' may be causing PHP to skip out on sending your email.